# ProxyPassReverse not showing the desired location

Tags: html, apache

I have installed RocketChat on my server, and I set up an apache2 virtualhost to use ProxyPassReverse to show the visitor localhost:3000 when they access rc.domain.com. 
 
Only problem is, it doesn't redirect you and shows an "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server.", no matter what you do. 
My etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin support@domain.com
ServerName rc.domain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/rc.domain.com_error.log
TransferLog /var/log/rc.domain.com_access.log
LogLevel info
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt

<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using Cloudflare's "Always use HTTPS" and its auto website encryption, if that helps.
Apache has another virtualhost running on port 80, and this virtualhost has a subdomain of the first one. Here's the ErrorLog output:

```
[Mon Mar 11 22:28:53.305103 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 1224] AH02568: Certificate and private key rc.example.com:443:0 configured from /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt and /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key 
[Mon Mar 11 22:28:53.722851 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 1225] AH01914: Configuring server rc.example.com:443 for SSL protocol
```

Rocketchat has no visible errors logged.
/var/log/apache2/access.log:

```
[my ip] - - [11/Mar/2019:23:01:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
```

EDIT: Fixed it! To anyone having this problem in the future: Try setting the port to 80 instead of 443, that fixed it for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Should Apache only act as a reverse proxy? What's in the logs?

Comment: Apache has another virtualhost running on port 80, and this virtualhost has a subdomain of the first one. Here's the ErrorLog output: `[Mon Mar 11 22:28:53.305103 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 1224] AH02568: Certificate and private key rc.example.com:443:0 configured from /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt and /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
[Mon Mar 11 22:28:53.722851 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 1225] AH01914: Configuring server rc.example.com:443 for SSL protocol
`
That's all it shows. @Zeta

Comment: Please add the additional information into the question itself with the [edit] button. An "edit" message is not necessary, as SO will keep the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55111166/revisions). Comments are second-class data snippets on this site and may get deleted after their associated issues have been resolved.

Comment: Also, is there any log in the RocketChat application (the one running on :3000)? That should also get added to the question.

Comment: @Zeta Alright, I added the info to my question. I checked Rocketchat's logs, and there doesn't seem to be any error logged.

Comment: Did you check the access/error logs? Keep in mind that you probably want to remove your IP address or other information from the logs before you post them. There must be a 403 in the logs at some point. That line will be a central key in this puzzle.

Comment: @Zeta I checked /var/log/apache2/access.log, the output is at the bottom of the question now.